# INSERT 18 FIELDS INTO A TABLE WHIT 19 FIELDS #SLQLITE

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert

TBL1 (18 COLUMNS)
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18

TBL2 (19 COLUMNS)
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19

I need to insert 18 columns with data into tbl2 and update column 19 with a concatenation from 2 columns from tbl1

Comment: Sorry i dont mean be rude i just type everything caps cause my keyboard was bad but if you give few minutes ill change all, so sorry my apologies to everyone

Comment: Much better now !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [insert into](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/):

```
insert into TBL2 
select *, colx || coly from TBL1
```

What is important here is the order of the columns, must be the same in both tables.